# Connection Refused when wrapping JMS Connection in ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, jms, activemq-classic, thread-local

Running into an issue where connection.start() fails due to

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

when I wrap my `javax.jms.TopicConnection` in a `ThreadLocal`, as follows:

```
private ThreadLocal<TopicConnection> createThreadLocalTopicConnection(final TopicConnectionFactory cf)
{
    return new ThreadLocal<TopicConnection>() {
        public TopicConnection result;

        protected synchronized TopicConnection initialValue() {
            try {
                // Returns a javax.jms.TopicConnection object.
                result = cf.createTopicConnection();
                result.start();
                return result;
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

            protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
                if(result!=null) result.close();
            }
        };
    }
```

If I just create the `TopicConnection` as a bare `static` variable, it connects without any issues.  Can anybody explain why it would work as a bare variable but when wrapped in a `ThreadLocal` it would fail?  Google has failed me pretty spectacularly this time around.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly why this is happening, but JMS clients are usually multi-threaded beasts, so I can see that this strategy might not be totally kosher.

JMS Connections are intended to be thread-safe, you you might want to just wrap your connection in a singleton or something. (JMS Sessions and below are not thread-safe and should  not be shared by threads, so you might consider putting the session in a thread local if you're committed to this approach).

Comment: The reason I wrapped it in a ThreadLocal is because when I simply declared the connection as static I was getting some odd side-effect behavior where intra-app messages weren't being received while inter-app messages were working as expected.  I am suspecting that some inter-thread configuration differences are the culprit.  Working with ActiveMQ's PooledConnectionFactory resolves the issue, but I'm trying to avoid stepping outside of the javax.jms references already in my code

Answer (score 0):

ThreadLocal would mean every Thread is getting it's own Connection.
Do compare how many threads the application is spawning vs the number of connections in the ActivationSpec

Comment: "ThreadLocal would mean every Thread is getting it's own Connection".  That was kind of the point.  Thanks though